When parsing YouTube using Puppeteer, I can't get the entire title list of videos from the playlist
I use puppeteer, I would like to move away from it altogether. I ran into such a problem that when I click on the link with the playlist of videos, I can only collect the first 100 titles, the remaining 26 are loaded later after.
my index.ts
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

async function fetchTitles(url: string): Promise<string[]> {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    // Прокрутка страницы вниз для загрузки всех видео
    await autoScroll(page);

    // Получение заголовков
    const titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll('h3.style-scope.ytd-playlist-video-renderer');
        const result: string[] = [];

        elements.forEach((element) => {
            const titleElement = element.querySelector('a#video-title');
            const title = titleElement && titleElement.textContent ? titleElement.textContent.trim() : '';
            if (title) result.push(title);
        });

        return result;
    });

    await browser.close();
    return titles;
}

// Функция автоматической прокрутки страницы
async function autoScroll(page: puppeteer.Page) {
    let previousHeight;
    let currentHeight = 0;

    while (previousHeight !== currentHeight) {
        previousHeight = currentHeight;
        currentHeight = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.scrollHeight);

        // Прокручиваем страницу
        await page.evaluate('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)');

        // Ждем, пока элементы появятся на странице
        await page.waitForSelector('h3.style-scope.ytd-playlist-video-renderer', {
            visible: true,
            timeout: 10000  // Таймаут для этого селектора (10 секунд)
        });
    }
}


// Использование функции с нумерацией
const url = 'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLnHJACx3NwAep5koWkniVHw8PK7dWCO21';
fetchTitles(url).then(titles => {
    const numberedTitles = titles.map((title, index) => `${index + 1}. ${title}`);
    console.log(numberedTitles);
});

my package.json
{
  "name": "youtubeparsev1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^23.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  },
  "private": true,
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}


my tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}


I would like not to use maybe puppeteer, I'm only collecting video titles.
I get only the first 100 titles from the playlist, and there are 123 videos in the playlist.
My result:
[ '1. React 18 Tutorial - Intro',
  '2. React 18 Tutorial - Setup',
  '3. React 18 Tutorial - Vite / Create React App',
  '4. React 18 Tutorial - Folder Structure',
  '5. React 18 Tutorial - Remove Boilerplate',
   /* ... */
  '100. React 18 Tutorial - Context API Setup'
]

